# "Seeking for an answer" or "seeking an answer"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase-meaning, prepositional-phrases

What is the difference between *seeking* *an* *answer* and *seeking* *for* *an* *answer*?

I found [an ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seeking+an+answer%2Cseeking+for+an+answer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cseeking%20an%20answer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseeking%20for%20an%20answer%3B%2Cc0) which says that *seeking* *an* *answer* is used much more often compared to *seeking* *for* *an* *answer* but how about the meaning? Do these two expressions mean the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'For' is implied by 'seeking' and therefore redundant.

In 'searching an answer,' 'for' is not implied and should be added.

One of those English mysteries, I guess.

Comment: Thanks Glasseyed, it makes sence. The ngram seems to show that the current usage of 'for' became redundant.

Comment: "sense," not "sence":-)

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in this good dictionary

[Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://books.google.ca/books?id=PDHCFSRmjSMC&pg=PA1292&dq=%22seeking%20for%22%20phrasal&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_6k6VdK1PKjksASmt4HYCw&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22seeking%20for%22%20phrasal&f=false)

> **Remember**: *Seek* is **not** usually followed by a preposition.
>
> NOT:  *I went to the beach seeking for peace and fresh air.*
>
> Correct: I went to the beach seeking peace and fresh air.

Answer (score 2):

'Seeking an answer' since 'seeking ' means 'looking for'.