# Seek help or Seek for help

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I am unable to find the correct answer. Please advise which one is correct?

1. Seek help from Mr.A
2. Seek for help from Mr.B

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Seeking for an answer" or "seeking an answer"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241470/seeking-for-an-answer-or-seeking-an-answer)

Answer (score 3):

1. Seek help from Mr. A.

This is grammatically correct. It is an example of an [imperative sentence](https://blog.udemy.com/declarative-sentence-examples/).